# Запуск потока в Servlet-е Java

Tags: java, android-asynctask

Подскажите пожалуйста как запустить другой поток в сервлете что бы в нём выполнить нужные действия?
Проблема в том что я делаю определенные действия на которые тратится не малое кол-во времени - скриншот экрана по url. Делаю я это AJAX запросом и проблема в том что пока это функция не отработает мне ответ не придёт. Хотелось бы что бы ответ приходил быстро. Иначе как другой поток я не знаю как сделать.
Гуглил, нашел такой пример:

```
@WebServlet("/foo" asyncSupported=true)
   public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
            ...
            AsyncContext aCtx = request.startAsync(req, res);
            ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10);
            executor.execute(new AsyncWebService(aCtx));
        }
   }

   public class AsyncWebService implements Runnable {
        AsyncContext ctx;
        public AsyncWebService(AsyncContext ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }
        public void run() {
            // Invoke web service and save result in request attribute
            // Dispatch the request to render the result to a JSP.
            ctx.dispatch("/render.jsp");
   }
}
```

Но у меня не работает пишет ошибку:

`A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations`

Хотя `asyncSupported=true` я поставил.

Как ещё можно запустить поток? Спасибо.

Comment: а какой у вас сервер? вам не важны результаты работы потока?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Tomcat 8. Важны. Мне же нужно сохранить скриншот и вернуть его путь.

Comment: @Tsyklop тогда вам в любом случае стоит дождаться окончания загрузки? или как вы себе представляли получить путь загрузки файлу который только загружается?

Comment: @Victor Сам файл мне не нужен. Мне нужен путь его. А его я генерирую так, до загрузки.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Подскажете? пожалуйста.

Comment: просто запустите отдельный поток. так как вы это сделали бы в настольном приложении.